# Does for every manifold $M$ exist a surjective continuous map $\phi:\Bbb R^d\to M$?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, manifolds

My question is basically in the title:

> Does for every $d$-dimensional *connected* manifold $M$ exist a *surjective continuous map* $\phi:\Bbb R^d\to M$?

I first thought that in the case of Riemannian manifolds the [exponential map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Riemannian_geometry)) shall do the trick, but it might not be surjective, right?
So if such a $\phi$ does not always exist, what are the weakest restrictions I need to make it exist, e.g. should $M$ be compact, differentiable, ...?

Comment: The exponential map is surjective if $M$ is equipped with a complete metric.  This can always be done for smooth manifolds.  For topological manifolds, I'd still bet they are images of $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does there always exist a continuous/smooth map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto a manifold $M^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2762450/does-there-always-exist-a-continuous-smooth-map-from-mathbbrn-onto-a-manif)